# Blocking all ip's except my public ip on UFW ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ssh, ufw, ubuntu-18.04

Im setting up a web server on 18.04 and I want to be able to block all ip's except my public ip from accessing ssh (22) on the UFW. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick assuming your public ip is `1.2.3.4`:

> sudo ufw allow from 1.2.3.4/32 to any port 22

Please refer to `man ufw` for more info.

I hope this helps.